Playwright session info not saving
I have a Cypress test which creates a customer and gets an insurance quote. I've replaced the UI steps of this process with a couple of API requests. The first registers the customer and the second gets a quote and returns the quote reference. I then use the quote reference in a URL to navigate directly to the payment screen.
I am now in the process of converting this test into Playwright and running into an issue where it will not navigate to the payment screen as it does with Cypress. I think this is something to do with a cookie that gets set by one of the API requests and maybe the session data isn't saved in the same way as in Cypress. Is anyone able to offer any suggestions to get this to work the same as Cypress please?

Please share a [mcve] showing the page under test, the working Cypress code, and the non-working Playwright code. It's extremely difficult to debug something nobody can see. Thanks.

I'll add what I can when I get chance. It won't be reproducible though because you won't have access to the API or test site. Thanks

Thanks. I suggest mocking the API and test site for the purposes of the question if you can. If not, at least the code may be enough for someone to help debug, bug likely not. See this meta canonical for more guidance on making a reprex for browser automation.

I managed to figure it out. Sorry for the lack of details in the original question. I'm a tester and not able to mock the API. I just test the site for others with tests they can reproduce.
Anyway, the problem was that I was making the API request like:
const registerResponse = await request.post(*registerCustomerUrl*, {
    data: {
        *JsonBody*
    }
});

Then I was opening the browser and navigating to the payment page with:
await page.goto(*paymentPageUrl*)

it knew nothing about the request context.
To fix, I had to change the way I was making the API requests to page.request:
const registerResponse = await page.request.post(*registerCustomerUrl*, {
    data: {
        *JsonBody*
    }
});

